# Cannot find module but module exist

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vue-router

I have this code to load route with vue-router asynchronously, I wanted it so I have menu (path) that can be changed / added dynamically from the superadmin side. But turns out, I need to load the component asynchronously, which kind of a bit tricky.

I have this function that return `Array<RouteConfig>`, and it is executed right after VueRouter is initialized.

It worked with this code.

```js
function getMenu() {
    let _routes = []
    await axios.get(url, {
        headers: {
            Authorization: store.state.token
        }
    }).then(res => {
        if (res.status == 200) {
            let data = res.data
            data.data.forEach(e => {
                let path =  e.path

                if(path.charAt(0) != '/') {
                    path = '/'+path
                }
                _routes.push({
                    path: path,
                    name: e.name,
                    component: function(resolve) {
                        require(['../views/Dashboard.vue'], resolve);
                    }
                })
            })
        } else {
            console.error('Something went wrong')
        }
    }).catch((e) => {
        console.error('Something went wrong: ' + e)
    })

    return _routes
}
```

But when I change the _routes.push() to like

(In which, I try to get a property of a response from API which is a variable)

```js
_routes.push({
    path: path,
    name: e.name,
    component: function(resolve) {
        require([e.component], resolve);
    }
})
```

It doesnt work, it says this error

```
Error: Cannot find module '../views/Dashboard.vue'
    at webpackEmptyContext (eval at ./src/router sync recursive (2.js:10), <anonymous>:2:10)
    at eval (dynamic.js?5ad6:37)
```

Sidenote: I know I should have used NuxtJS for this, but we already went too far, and going back would cost a lot more. Any workaround is accepted.

Comment: can you share your directory `module path` and `script path`

Comment: You may take a look here https://pasteboard.co/K7Jej08.png

Comment: but your `Dashboard.vue` inside the warehouse directory

Comment: try   `../views/warehouse/Dashboard.vue`

Comment: No, it's not. Its not inside `warehouse`. I have tried `../views/Dashboard.vue` it work, but when I use `e.component` which has the same value, it is not working

Comment: I don't think require will work with a completely dynamic variable.   can you try doing something like ```require(`../views/${viewName}.vue`);```

Comment: Holy cow it works!! @StevenB. You save my life dude, such a silly JS case lol, thank you so much for everyone

Comment: i think it's because it needs to know what to include at build time.